# Version control on google play

Tags: android, google-play

I updated my application from v.4 to v.5 with the wrong .apk file. When I try to revert back to v.4, I get an error that says, "Error: New APK version is lower than previous APK version." When I try to activate both versions, I get a similar erorr saying, "Error: APK version 4 supports all the same devices as other APKs with higher versions. It would not be served. Please deactivate an APK."

So, is there any way I can delete v.5 and revert back to v.4? I can't find this question or an answer to this question anywhere. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If reactivating previous version is not possible then why google keep all the older version in google play? what is the point here? why google want to load it server with unusable apks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I emailed the google play support team and they responded, saying that there is no option to delete a higher version and revert back to the previous version of the apk. The only option is to upload a higher version.

(Imo, this is a big problem because many people submit apps to google play for academic competitions (or even just academic projects) where deadlines must be met. Without checking the google play timezone, you can submit an update at 8pm your time on 3/20, but that might appear as 3/21 on the website. Then you're just sol/disqualified.)